# Automatic Gate integration

Tags: home-automation

I have an automatic gate controlled by a board named MACH2 230 with the features specified in this [link](http://www.dieffematic.com/documenti/MACH2230multi.pdf) that contains the spreadsheet of the board.

Is there a way to integrate the MACH2 230 board with a Raspberry Pi 3 model B to control the gate with that? Can anyone suggest me a way to do that **(possibly in a figurative)** way and the components that i need?

[image]

following the suggestion in the comment i need to connect the relays of RaspBerry with the buttons: **gate1** and **gate2** illustated in the board image. 
How i can do that?

Comment: [The manual](http://www.apritech.it/docs/series_docs/42/MACH2_230_multi_(vE).pdf) is completely miserable. Looks like there are a lot of switch inputs for opening and closing though. Why would you need a Pi if you can just hook in a switch? What's the plan?

Comment: @goobering i want build a recognition system with raspberry cam  and Deep Net or Adaboost classifier, thus i need to integrate the raspi with this automatic gate board or i need to replace it with raspberry, but i cannot able to do that and i'm evaluating if it possible :)

Comment: I wouldn't even think about replacing that board. Just use the switch inputs that are already there. Figure out which ones open and close the gate, wire suitable relays over them and control the relays with the Pi.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for your answer. Can you show me in a figurative way how to do that pls?

Comment: Not so much - that manual isn't informative enough for me to figure out which pins do what to the door. You'll need to either experiment with it (*very carefully* - bits of the board are carrying 220V) or contact the manufacturer for some better instructions. Using a relay (an electronically controlled switch) with a Pi isn't difficult, and is [widely written up](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=K3WUWL7zJ8XO8gf9i4j4Cg#q=raspberry+pi+relay). If I'm right about how the gate works, you can use relays to open and close the switch connections that open and close the gate.

Comment: the photo of the board can help u? i can take it. This this are the [specification](http://www.apritech.it/docs/series_docs/42/MACH2_230_multi_(vE).pdf) of the manufactorer

Comment: That's the same one I linked to in my first comment. I'm sorry but there just isn't enough information in the manual. You'll need to do some experimenting.

Comment: @goobering i've found also that [image](http://www.telecommande.info/FicheProduit/photo.php?uid=0302s9ki8u4eeoqesbeeqqq77980k41486126402&reference_photo=platine_mach2-230) that for me is more figurative if it can help